# WP as an HTML editor

Tags: visual-editor

Is WP a good HTML editor?

A friend of mine wants to create HTML pages, but doesn't know 
HTML. Can WP become a WYSIWIG HTML editor via the appropriate plugin?

He'll be formatting images, wanting to place text in specific 
locations, etc. Nothing too fancy, but not just text either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is a CMS (Content Management System) and not an editor.

That being said WordPress does have a simple WYSIWIG style editor built into it for formatting the content that you want to post.

Comment: This was the first answer, and it succinctly answered my question, so giving it the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress editor uses TinyMCE for the rich text fields. if this is just to produce static html, maybe you can [download the full TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and put it on a local static page for them.

Comment: Oh, he wants to use the rest of WordPress' power too (posts, categories, etc), but I was just worried his lack of HTML knowledge might slow him down. I suppose he could edit in TinyMCE and cut/paste to WP... hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Your question although written well seems a bit vaugue on reading, wordpress comes with its own WYSIWYG editor (as the others have said.. TinyMCE)..

TinyMCE inside wordpress (and anywhere else as standard) has both html and WYSIWYG (visual) editing, for me TinyMCE in wp is ok, if i need to edit anything i always do it in html mode anyway, however there is a plugin for ckeditor for wordpress (never tried it) which has some good reviews [ckeditor for wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/), only used it when custom building none wp sites but its a learning curve, nice editor though..

Answer (score 0):

If your friend want to start learning HTML I suggest he uses a simple HTML editor software first, not a CMS like Wordpress.

For example with [Bluegriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org/) he can make his first pages and test them locally in the browser. Also he can switch between code view (nicely formatted and unfiltered, unlike in WP) and WYSIWYG, allowing him to understand how one influences the other.

Making his first steps that way will be much faster and profitable in the long run in my opinion.